# How many times can a word be created using the input string?

Tags: python

Here is the problem I'm trying to solve:

Write a program to perform the following operations:

- Read two inputs - a sequence of characters S & another shorter sequence Y from two separate lines of input
- S only contains lower case characters among a-z
- Calculate and print how many times the given word Y can be generated from the given sequence S
- Characters from string S can be used in order
- Each character can be used only once

**Sample Input:**

apqrctklatc //input

cat         //the word that we need to create from input

**Output:**

word cat can be formed 2 times

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read through the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Your best bet here is to do your research, search for related topics on SO, and give it a go. After doing more research and searching, post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck, which can help you get better answers.

Comment: Beginners are welcome, but we expect a certain amount of effort to be expended on attempting to solve your own problem prior to a question being posted. We don't write code for you although we are very willing to help you fix issues with code you have written.

Comment: split both strings and find the occurrences of every character and push or append the number of occurrences of every character to array or list then print minimum from them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this:

```py
s = 'apqrctklatc'
y = 'cat'
yc = []
for i in y:
    yc.append(s.count(i))
print(min(yc))
```

This, according to me is the simplest solution.

Let's see how it works:

1) It loops through the second string(`'cat'`).

2)It counts how many times each letter in the string occurs in the other string, i.e. `'apqrctklatc'` and makes a list.

3)It finds the minimum value of the list formed, i.e. `yc`.

Comment: Thanks! This works! I just had to use input() for both s and y instead of hardcoded values

Answer (score 0):

My solution is:

- Step 1: Count the number of times that each distinct characters appear in the 2nd input. Save the result to a map, called `mapA`, for example: a - 2 times, b - 3 times, etc...
- Step 2: Iterate through the 1st input, count the number of times that each characters in `mapA` appear. Save the result to a map, called `mapB`.
- Step 3: Initialize a variable with a high integer value (`max_int` is a good choice), called `result`. Iterate through `mapA` (or `mapB`, since both maps have the same list of keys). For each keys in `mapA`, calculate the floor of `mapB.value/mapA.value`. If it smaller than `result`, set `result` to that value.
- Step 4: Return the `result`, which is the result you need.

For other cases that make your result unexpected, like: 1st input and 2nd input have no common character, etc..., make sure that you have catch all of them before following those steps. Hope that you can finish it without a sample code.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
import re 
s="apqrctklatc"
y="cat"

ylst = [x for x in y]

print(ylst)

ycount=[]
for ychar in ylst:

    count = len(re.findall(ychar, s)) 

    ycount.append(count)

print("word",y," can be formed",min(ycount),"times")
```

it's working for me also you can see my output:

[image: output screenshot]